# more pages at one A4

Tags: tex-general

How can I write a MWE (LaTeX source) that puts 6 pages along A4, three in each row,
and at the same time, controls the spaces in between them and sizes of these ?

**EDIT** *Working* on-line tool will be the best for me. This one, say, https://online2pdf.com/multiple-pages-per-sheet# yields small pages instead of entered 2mm in between two of them:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `pgfpages` package

Comment: Or `pgfmorepages`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for your hint. However I'm quite new to this package and unable to create the MWE. Could you please be more specific how to do that ? When I print from Firefox I'm getting bad results: the sizes of the pages are smaller than they could be.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the `pgfpages` package. It comes with a predefined `6 on 1` layout and to some extend you can control the size of the pages via the `border shrink` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{6 on 1}[border shrink=-12mm]

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

\duckument
\duckument
\duckument

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need more fine control over the size and position, you can define your own layouts, see the package documentation for details.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. What I need is to **reduce** the gaps in between the pages to say, 2milimeters. I'm completely unable to achieve that despite what I've tried so far.

Comment: @user2925716 Due to the aspect ration of a4 pages, there will always be big horizontal gaps in a 6 on 1 layout (or very large margins). For smaller vertical gaps, decrease the `border shrink` parameter or define a new layout

Comment: OK, I'll try. But now the pages are themselves pdf. How can I include them ?