# more pages on one sheet with **cut off margins** and `pdfpages`

Tags: xetex, pdfpages, printing

I have recently asked a similar question [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653752/more-pages-at-one-a4) but I still haven't obtained an answer I was looking for. This time I shall be much more precise (which will even yield a new question rather than trying to fix the old one) together with providing  MWE: an attempt I made to solve it. I want to use `pdfpages` to put 2x3 pages on A4 paper, which
is now OK, but I cannot achieve the simple obvious thing that the small pages won't be so small and will be put side by side with the distance **zero:** 0pt (line on the page 1 continues with the corresponding line on page the 2 and that one on the page 3) **and** occupying entire A4: no blank margins anywhere on the sheet. As you can see
in my MWE I have tried to put the parameter delta negative and many other attempts,
but aside that the 6 pages are moving around and appearing in different sizes on my A4 sheet, nothing works as wanted. Is it such a difficult problem to achieve cutting-off the margins, or is my approach completely wrong ?

I understand that 0pt in both directions would yield deformed text, but I don't care at the moment about this problem, just horizontal 0pt distance of pages 1, 2 and 3 would be great. In the end, I want to print 1 page of 6 page-long-paper which will be, due to resizing the logical pages, still readable. After all, you can see the paper on the snippet below. Finally, I'm surprised that such natural problem has no available solution on stackexchange-at least I was unable to locate one though I've made many attempts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{slides}
\usepackage[enable-survey]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[survey-nolink, nup=2x3,delta=-20pt -10pt]{AA.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default there is no space, but perhaps your pages have large margins. You could clip them to enlarge the contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[nup=2x3,pages=1-6,landscape,trim=1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\includepdf[nup=2x3,pages=1-6,landscape,trim=6cm 8cm 6cm 8cm,clip]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Ulrike, excellent. A final question: Can I increase the resolution of the printed stuff so that it would be more easily readable ? Where can I do so ?